# Как записать данные с HTML-формы в переменную?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Допустим, у меня есть HTML-документ с формой, `index.html`. Как мне записать данные, которые юзер введет в форму, в переменную? Покажите, пожалуйста, самый простой пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте объект `params` в обработчике
*POST*-запроса:

```ruby
require "sinatra"

get "/" do
  erb <<~EOF
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
    <input name="name"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
  EOF
end

post "/" do
  puts "hello from #{ params["name"] }"
  # N.B.              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  redirect "/", 303
end
```